# Extracting a string with sed

Tags: regex, shell, sed

I've checked a few articles and found `sed` with regex. I mapped the tips to my problem, but without success.

This is not working for me:

```
echo "uri=https://myserver.domain.de:1234" | sed 's|//\(.+\):|\1|'
```

I expected

```
myserver.domain.de
```

But got the whole string

```
uri=https://myserver.domain.de:1234
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to match the part before the match and after it, and replace `+` with `*` (or escape the `+`, which will make it work in GNU `sed` with the BRE POSIX pattern):

```
echo "uri=https://myserver.domain.de:1234" | sed 's|.*//\(.*\):.*|\1|'
```

Result: `myserver.domain.de`.

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/e3nAL5).

Here is an [alternative pattern](https://ideone.com/tzxKSB):

```
sed 's|.*//\([^:]*\).*|\1|'
```

where `.*` inside the capturing group is replaced with `[^:]*` (any 0+ chars other than `:`, see below).

**Details**

- `.*` - any 0+ chars, as many as possible, up to the last occurrence of subsequent subpatterns
- `//` - a `//` substring
- `\(.*\)` -  Group 1: any 0+ chars as many as possible (or, to constrain the engine a bit, you may use `[^:]*` here instead of `.*` (to match any 0+ chars other than `:`)
- `:` - a colon
- `.*` - the rest of the line

The `\1` backreference will keep the captured value only.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution now:

```
echo "uri=https://myserver.domain.de:1234" | sed -r 's|(.+//)([^:]+)(:.+)|\2|'
```

answer

```
myserver.domin.de
```

Comment: You don't have to capture the groups 1 and 3 in them. It would be an overkill

Comment: @tbasien: It is basically my pattern written in POSIX ERE syntax (with `+` instead of `*`, I also noted the quantifier). If my solution works please consider accepting my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for sed here. Here's a way to do it using a portable POSIX feature called [*parameter expansion*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02):

```
full="uri=https://myserver.domain.de:1234"
withoutport="${full%:[[:digit:]]*}" # Strip the trailing port number (":1234")
desired="${withoutport#uri=https://}" # Strip the undesired prefix
printf '%s\n' "$desired"
```

You can read more about it here in [*Open Group Standard Vol. 3: Shell and Utilities, Issue 7: 2.6.2 Parameter Expansion*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) at The Open Group Publications Server.

If you insist on using sed, however, then here is pretty readable solution:

```
sed -e 's,^uri=https://,,' -e 's,:[0-9]\+$,,'
```